# Two meanings of "belisle"

Tags: meaning

Whereas " belisle "  is a  French word as well as English indicating a trap for foxes, 
http://www.snareshop.com/products.asp?dept=468
it's surprising to find it elsewhere with a  very shocking meaning  as shown there :
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Belisle

the etymology of belisle is "belle île" which means "beautiful island"

but I don't know why "belisle" means "fox trap" nor the link between it and a sexual violence.
Could you explain where this distortion comes from ? Many thanks

Comment: Can you cite anything else for it being an English word for fox traps as well as a French word? Based on your first website, it might just be a *make* or *model* of fox trap, not a word meaning fox trap. Also, I can't find it in any French dictionaries. That etymology you gave seems dubious. Like the fact that some claim that the city Buffalo is named after the French *beau fleuve*, meaning beautiful river. It's probably not true, but sounds nice.

Comment: The fox-trap looks like a trade name to me. As to the alternative meaning ? The OED has never heard of the word. The Urban Dictionary says it is an adjective and then proceeds to give an example of it used as an adverb! The only thing Google comes up with is as a proper noun surname, particularly that of a major-league baseball player - Matt Belisle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it considers a proper name part as being part of the lexicon in that usage.

Answer (score 1):

"belisle" is sounding French, but it is a proprietary eponym (a generic trademark).

*An eponym is someone or something whose name is or is thought to be the source of something's name. For example,:"kleenex", "velcro" or "post-it"*.

I translated the first paragraph from this [link](http://www.piegeurs.com/dossier-016.html):

> When I visited Quebec, I toured the BELISLE trap factory. Some years
>   ago, the fox traps were invented by Edouard BELISLE.

For the shift to sexual violence, I believe that the trap evokes sado-masochistic accessories:

[image]

Comment: I don't think "kleenex," "velcro," and "post-it" are eponyms. Eponyms are *people* who've lent their names to things or the names or nouns which are the result of this lending. "Kleenex", etc. are simply brand names that have become nouns through the process of "nominalization" or "genericization."

Comment: @Silenus - From [Wikipedia]: A generic trademark, also known as a genericized trademark or *proprietary eponym*, is a trademark or brand name that has become the generic name for, or synonymous with, a general class of product or service, usually against the intentions of the trademark's holder.

Comment: @Gaffito, that's fair enough!